# How do I remove roles from a user?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently trying to add reaction roles to my bot, but I'm having trouble getting the bot to remove roles when the reactions are removed

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print("Reaction Added")
    if ((payload.message_id == 874372383736205343) and (payload.emoji.name == '')):
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        role = guild.get_role(874364790099836948)
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    print("Reaction Removed")
    if ((payload.message_id == 874372383736205343) and (payload.emoji.name == '')):
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        role = guild.get_role(874364790099836948)
        await payload.remove_roles(role)
```

Adding roles works perfectly as intended but whenever I try removing a reaction I always get some kind of error. I've tried a few different things, but the code that I provided returns "Attribute Error: "RawReactionAddEvent" object has no attribute "remove_roles"
As I said, I've tried things other than remove_roles but none of them worked.

I'm pretty new to discord.py and python as a whole so this is probably a really obvious mistake but I just can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: you forgot to put .member in the last line, it should be payload.member.remove_roles(role) (going by the patern of the role add, i dont actually know for sure this will fix it)

Comment: @FierySpectre docs: `payload.member: The member who added the reaction. Only available if event_type is REACTION_ADD and the reaction is inside a guild.`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to retrieve a member object in order to remove the roles. You're currently trying to remove a role from `payload` instead of a valid member.

```
guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
role = guild.get_role(874364790099836948)
await member.remove_roles(role)
```

As Lukasz points out, you can't use `payload.member` when a reaction is removed because it is only available when a reaction is added. [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=raw%20reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.member).